# Sending HTTP PUT request using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, xmlhttprequest

HI am trying to make an HTTP PUT request to my API. I am getting back the error 405 and 415 depending on how I change the URL.

The ID I am trying to change is 26 and I want to change the `testDesc` to `test5`.

Any ideas? Thank you for your time.

```js
function httpPut() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://someurl/Test/26",
    type: "PUT",
    'data': {
      testDesc: "test5",
    },
  }).done(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("testingBox7").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  });
};
```

Comment: 405 and 415 errors imply that your server side code is not configured to receive PUT requests to the endpoint you're using. Note that you can't just change the HTTP verb - your server side code needs to have its routing configured to receive it. As such your problem is on the server side, not the client side JS.

Comment: Show your server code also.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

```js
function httpPut(newName) {
  var myString = "https://https://someurl/Test/";
  $.ajax({
    url: myString + newName,
    type: "PUT",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).done(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("testingBox7").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  });
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.